# Android WeekDayPickerDialog

Tags: android, android-widget

i would like a PickerDialog for picking weekdays a little like the TimePickerDialog in the SDK do anyone know of an ready made implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [Date Picker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html) from the [Hello Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) tutorial?

Comment: i found what i need in the alertdialog using multiple-choice items, but thanks to the link it will help me with the other settings i need to edit.